# How can I add another field for the current user?

Tags: reactjs, firebase

[image: This is my firestore. I wanted to add in the field for that user assuming that she was the currentUser.]

[image: But this is what happens, it created another document of users with a field of Address]
I wanted to add another field for the current user. Currently, I can add another field but it is created in another document.

```
const { currentUser } = useSelector(mapState);

const userRef = firestore.collection('users').doc(currentUser.uid);

    async function addAddress() {
       const res = await userRef.set({
           'Address' : 'Ayala'
       }, { merge : true});
    }
```

Comment: Please descibe your goal better. It's unclear where you want to add that "Address"-Entry.
Right now, I see no problem wih your code

Comment: I wanted to add the field "address"  under an existing document. What the code did was add another field of address but in another document.

Comment: then your collection or document key is wrong, that code should totally work

Comment: I don't why it's still not working. Is it because the uid was auto generated?

Comment: where does the script saves the address? just give an expected path and the real path please

Comment: I edited the question and added pictures. What happens with the code is that, it added another document with those fields

Comment: try logging `currentUser.uid` after you set the userRef, looks like the uid is `users`

Comment: I've fixed it already thank you. It was currentUser.id, my bad. Still, thank you